# Google Sheet Script conditionally set value of blank cells to today's date but leave existing data the same

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am stumped with what is probably a simple problem.

I have a column of data, J, that has a date in some of the cells, but not all.  If the cell is blank, I need to write today's date in that cell.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var event=[];
var date= new Date();

for (event=1; event< destSheet.length; event ++){
    if (destSheet[event][10]<1){
        [event][10]=date;
  }
  }
```

No errors are returned, it simply does not write in a date (I will worry about format later). What have I done wrong?

Comment: `[event][10]=date;` This is an error. The 11th element of `[some number]` is `undefined`. There are just too many in such a small piece of code..

Comment: I tried using ==undefined first, and it did not work either....

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line `[event][10]=date` inside the `if`? And  also why do you reuse the variable `event`? In JS `event` is reserved and I don't think you can even use that as a variable. (See how it is blue in the code block above?)

Comment: It is setting an event date, hence I used the word 'event' as the variable name.  I am trying to set the cell value to today's date (date=new Date ()) if it is blank.  I reset the variable name to another word, and set it == to undefined, and still nothing...

Comment: Well, `event` is not a Date even if you can use it. `event` is a number starting from `1` to `destSheet.length`.

Comment: OK, so how do I write a value in the cell [event][10]?  Event refers to the row number, 10 to the column number.  Do I use setValue?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like the following code.  The code builds a 2 dimensional array to overwrite existing data with the same data, and put a new date in cells that are blank.

```
function xyz() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  //getRange(start row, start column, numRows, number of Columns)
  var rangeData = sourceSheet.getRange(2,1, sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);

  var dataFromSheet = rangeData.getValues();
  var date= new Date();

  var i=0,
      thisCellValue,
      innnerArray = [],
      outerArray = [];

  for (i=0; i< dataFromSheet.length; i+=1){
    thisCellValue = dataFromSheet[i];

    if (thisCellValue === ""){
      innnerArray.push(date);
      outerArray.push(innnerArray);
    } else {
      innnerArray.push(thisCellValue); //To overwrite original data with the same data
      outerArray.push(innnerArray);
    }; 
  };

  sourceSheet.getRange(2,1, outerArray.length, innerArray[0].length).setValues(outerArray);
};
```